# Scrolling titles like in Google play

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem while creating tabs on android. I want them to look like in Google play. I've made scrolling tabs already following [this sample](http://code.google.com/p/android-playground/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSwipeyTabsSample%2Fsrc%253Fstate%253Dclosed), but the titles still look like this i.imgur.com/SKYd2.png.

But I want them to be scrolled like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWV1J.jpg).

I'm using ActionBarSherlock. I've searched for several days to find the solution, but I wasn't lucky. All I've met is swiping tabs, but not titles.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have You checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html ?

Comment: It's kind of similar to ViewPagerIndicator I guess. [This sample](http://neta-abc.blogspot.com/2012/07/pagertabstrip.html) is great.  Thank you!

Comment: Superb sample nenuka. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `TabPageIndicator` from http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: This library probably is created for [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) support, so you need just download and add as library. You don't need use `ActionBarSherlock` in your projects.

Comment: Yes, that works, but all the samples were so huge, I couldn't understand them. [This](http://neta-abc.blogspot.com/2012/07/pagertabstrip.html) helped me a bit. 
Thanks!